# Changing nvarchar fields fails in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 with weird message

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to edit a value in a table with about 50 columns using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 (10.50.2500.0). One of the columns is a normal standard text column for email (no constraints, no FKs, nothing):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Members](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
          ....
    [Email] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
          ....
```

I do right-click on the table, click "Edit top 200 rows", choose a row and update email from "aaa" to "bbb". I get this error message when I try to leave the row:

> Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> No row was updated.
>
> The data in row 2 was not committed. Error Source: mscorlib. Error
>   Message: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count
>   is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the
>   source collection.
>
> Correct the errors and retry or press ESC to cancel the change(s).
>
> OK   Help

If I update the value using SQL script, it works just fine:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Members] SET [Email] = 'bbb' WHERE Email = 'aaa'
```

Any idea what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: Does the table have a primary key set?

Comment: @RThomas - nope, no primary keys here. Is it the reason?..

Comment: Why would you have built a table without a PK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm... i think i found the answer:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vstsdb/thread/4ea43c84-15c8-4f63-967f-6944f1d71660

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/155528/offset-and-length-were-out-of-bounds-for-the-array-or-count-is-greater-than-the-number-of-elements-from-index-to-the-end-of-the-source-collection

looks like a known bug in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a primary key on the table to use the 'edit' feature reliably.

In your query "update where" will get any and all rows that match the where clause be that one or many.  With the edit tool however it knows the update should only be for one row, but due to a lacking PK cannot figure out safely which one.

From my experience the only time you can safely use the edit tool without a PK is when all the rows are distinctly valued making (in essence) the entire row the PK.

Comment: PLus it is a really bad idea to edit records through the GUI anyway. Changes to data should be scripted and put into sourcecontrol so they can easily be ported to other environments.

Comment: @RThomas - my bad, i was looking at the code I provided when I said no PK - and for some reason I forgot that PK is defined AFTER the table is created. Of course there is a primary key - which is ID column.

Comment: @HLGEM - i hear you but I needed to do one-time fix on live database.